# Running A Linux Based Distro On A Samsung Chromebook?

Tags: support, scope

I would like to ask the following question on Superuser, but before posting would like to know if it is suitable or not:

Is it possible to run a linux based distro eg Ubuntu on a Samsung Chromebook alongside the Chrome OS. Is the installation process of Ubuntu any different from installing on a regular Windows 7/8 laptop, if so how to install ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions sounds perfectly fine for Super User.

In the future, you can also drop by our little [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118/root-access) to get quick feedback about a question you'd like to ask.

Comment: OliverSalzburg Thanks very much for the advice on the question & the use of the Chat room :)

Answer (score 0):

The question seems fine.

It might be useful to point out to those reading what research you've done in determining the result for yourself before running out of ideas as to how to proceed.  This helps because they won't rehash crap you've already read and discarded.